# jquery animate image sliding out behind ul list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I am trying to make an image slide out on hover and then slide back once they hover to a new link but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here's the JS

```
$(function() {
  $('#menu_seo > li').hover(
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('span',$this).stop().animate({
            'right':'70px'
        }).css({
            'zIndex':'10'
        });
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('span',$this).stop().animate({
            'right':'-10px'
        }).css({
            'zIndex':'-1'
        });
    }
  );
});
```

and my CSS:

```
#menu_seo {
    position:relative;
}

ul#menu_seo li span {
    height:60px;
    width:15px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
    cursor:pointer;
}

ul#menu_seo li span.arrowout1 {
    background-image:url(../arrow.png);
    top:8px;
    left:230px;
}
```

anyone see my problem here?

Comment: You should probably set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) for this?

Comment: I took a first stab at a jsFiddle, but can't figure out the HTML structure. http://jsfiddle.net/M6cdT/

Comment: sorry http://jsfiddle.net/ATPG9/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you can not do this animation with `z-index`, you should create a mask area with css `overflow:hidden` property and hide the animating objects with `position`.

Second thing, you can not animate an object `right` when that object's css got `left` property, this will create a conflict and won't work. Position values must be accurate.

And i suggest you to use jQuery bind method, it is solid and you can use multiple events with this, like: click, hover, mouseenter, mouseleave.

Here is working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ATPG9/11/

**jQuery:**

```
$('#menu_seo li').bind({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $(this).children('span').stop().animate({'right':'70px'},200);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).children('span').stop().animate({'right':'-50px'},200);
    }
});
```

**css:**

```
#left_aside {
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    width:230px;
    height:900px;
    background-color:#f2dada;
}

ul#menu_seo li span    {
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    right:-50px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you I have been scratching my head for awhile now, worked perfectly

Comment: quick question I have copied your code exactly and im using the latest version of firefox   <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Untitled-3.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Untitled-4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>...thats in my head section but its not sliding now that i did it outside of jsfiddle

Comment: You should wrap this code with `document.ready() { .. }` http://api.jquery.com/ready/ in your question you used different type of ready: `$(function() { .. }`